# Extract an Page Variant Value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

I am not a javascript expert at all and expect this to be a fairly simple task.

I am trying to grab the value from a hidden field on my page called pageVariant so I can store it as a value inside of Google Tag Manager. I just don't know how to write the javascript.

[image]

This is the code I have tried, but know it is not right. Any help here would be appreciated.

```js
function() {
  var capturedText = document.querySelector("#lp-pom-form-162 > form > input[type=hidden]:nth-child(2)");
  return capturedText; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all provide a name to your `function`.

Then use the code mentioned below:

```
    function inputText() {
      var capturedText = document.querySelector("input[name='pageVariant']").value;
      return capturedText; 
    }
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to add an id to the hidden element, unfortunately. But I do have an input name. Can I use that instead?

Comment: Yes you can do that. I have update the code according to your requirement. @Avenues_Q

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept the answer now?

Comment: @Avenues_Q if you're okay with the answer, can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Yes. I want to do that. I am not sure where that button is.